# media screen codes in CSS not working as desired

Tags: css, responsive-design

My web site is not working for a mobile device whose width showing 393. please help. 
A snap  of My CSS Codes are as under.

```
/*----------------------------~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
/* FOR MEDIA QUERY (RESPONSIVE)  settings for mobile/tabs etc */
/*----------------------------~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
    /*---------------------------------- */
    /* for different width */
@media screen 
    and (max-width:1572px)
    and (max-width:500px)
    and (max-width:600px)
    and (max-width:460px)
    and (max-width:393px) {

    #divHeader {
        float: none;

    }   
    #mainH1{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }

    #divMiddle{
        float: none;
        height:500px;
        width: 90%; 

        }   
    #divGlobe{
        float: none;
        height: 500px;
        width: 90%
        }   

    }
```

Snap of my main page where I have defined settings of CSS files and codes for responsive web page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name= "index.html" content="html self made web site "> 
    <meta name= "keywords" content="web design, affordable and professional">
    <meta name="description" content="Affordable and smart web desing without any builders rather via self made codes">
    <meta name="Author" content="Binod Binani">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--Css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../html-web/sc-css/sc_style1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../html-web/java-js/slides.js" ></script>
    <title>#Sharp Compusoft#</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using max-width, follow the order from hi resolution to lo resolution. Keep the @media seperated.

```
#something {
  /* all resolutions */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1572px) {
  #something {
    /* here all css for 1572px and smaller */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #something {
    /* here all css for 600px and smaller */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #something {
    /* here all css for 500px and smaller */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  #something {
    /* here all css for 460px and smaller */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 393px) {
  #something {
    /* here all css for 393px and smaller */
  }
}
```

If you want the @media to target a "from-to" resolution, then use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 461px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  #something {
    /* here css for displays between 461px - 500px */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It worked perfectly. Nice to hear from you. Many many thanks